# Trying to follow Single Responsibility Principle with download and show progress

Tags: javascript, node.js, animation, network-file-transfer

Let's get right into it, I have a function `downloadFile(url, path);` Downloads file and saves it.

**donwloadFile.js**

```js
module.exports = function donwloadFile(url, path) {
    return new Promise(res => {
        return axios({ url, method: 'GET', responseType: 'stream', })
            .then(({ data }) => {
                const file = createWriteStream(path);
                data.pipe(file);
                file.on('finish', () => {
                    file.close();
                    res({ ok: true });
                });
            })
            .catch(err => res({ ok: false, err }))
    });
}
```

Just there it already seems to violate SRP which i don't know what i can do about since the two functionality are part of each other, downloading and saving.

Ignoring that however, it's perfectly fine, it gets the job done and tells you what's going on.

to download a file you provide the `url` and the `path` where to save, simple.

---

However my main issue is that i want to add a progressBar *(using progress library)* to give some feedback and in order to do that i need to have access to `data` parameter of `axios` and the code becomes as follows.

**donwloadFile.js**

```js
module.exports = function donwloadFile(url, path) {
    return new Promise(res => {
        return axios({ url, method: 'GET', responseType: 'stream', })
            .then(({ data }) => {
                const file = createWriteStream(path);
                data.pipe(file);

                const progressBar = new ProgressBar('[:bar] :percent | Time left: :etas.', {
                    complete: '=',
                    incomplete: ' ',
                    renderThrottle: 1,
                    total: parseInt(data.headers['content-length'])
                })
                data.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    progressBar.tick(chunk.length);
                })

                file.on('finish', () => {
                    file.close();
                    res({ ok: true });
                });
            })
            .catch(err => res({ ok: false, err }))
    });
}
```

and suddenly the download function isn't just downloading it's also spitting out a progressBar which is not ideal.

---

I had the idea of passing a `callback` which would be called inside `data.on('data', callback)`

But then we're doing the same thing again, the download function should only take two arguments, having a third one as callback makes it look like it's doing more than it says.

---

So my question is:

How can i keep the download function only downloads and also have the ability to  show a progress bar ?

Also I'd welcome any healthy criticism, writing pretty and maintainable code has always been the bane of my existence, and i just got fed up and decided to learn some concepts.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. While your concerns about the code are valid, our goal here is to help you improve your coding skills by providing insightful observations about working code from your projects. We don't help write the code. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @pacmaninbw How is this asking to write code ? I've already provided everything and only asking how i can refactor it to maintain a rule of clean code while having the same functionality. If this isn't what **Code Review Community** is about, Could you point me to which of the stackexchange communities that are appropriate for such question.

Comment: You have already made most of the observations anyone could make about the code. Please note I did provide an answer as well. I did not down vote the question or vote to close it. Please read the `How do I ask a good question?` link so your questions are a better fit in the future. `How to` questions are off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: Perhaps your understanding of SRP is a little misguided. The first version of `downloadFile.js` seems fine to me.

Comment: @hfontanez Yes i just wasn't sure about it so i decided to ask while i'm at it, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You could design the download function to return a file and then call a save file function if you want to. It might be a cleaner solution that way. But, if the general expectation is that every downloaded file must be saved, then you could argue that the implementation does obey SRP. So, in this case, it is a matter of code reusability. If you find yourself copying the same "save" functionality in other parts of the code, then you have a refactoring opportunity. To obey Open/Close principle, typically what I do is to create a new version of a function, so that the legacy code remains  intact.

Comment: @ZohirSalak this should answer your question or get you REALLY close: https://usefulangle.com/post/68/javascript-ajax-download-file

Comment: So if i'm to show progress a function won't cut it, i might as well write a download class with a progress event that i can subscribe to which is basically equivalent to passing a callback to a function might be more cleaner that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Is SRP being violated?

I think the first version of `donwloadFile.js` is fine and obeys SRP. That said, I believe a cleaner solution is to refactor this method to return a file and then create a function that saves the file. I believe this is what @*pacmaninbw* suggested in his or her answer.

### When to refactor?

If you find that you are copying the same lines to save a file in other parts of the code, you found yourself a refactoring opportunity. Now the question is how would you refactor. The way I have handled this in the past, and to stay true to ***Open/Close Principle*** (OCP), is to include a new version of the same method with this refactoring in place. In other words, I ***expand*** the functionality, instead of ***modifying*** it. That way, legacy code can continue to call the old `downloadFile.js`, while new code calls the new version. In fact, sometimes I would modify the legacy function where the legacy function will call the new function. To me, it is OK for legacy functions to depend on new functions (obviously, not the other way around).

### What advantage does this approach have?

I can think of two:

1. You won't have to worry about failing test cases due to unforeseen side effects of this modification
2. If you ever retire the legacy code, you don't have to worry about dependencies (new functions don't depend on old functions).

So, in my humble opinion, even if `downloadFile.js` violates SRP, the best way to handle it might be leaving it alone and simply expand your functionality by adding a new version (or variant). That said, if the code is not in production yet, feel free  to make all the modifications needed to have the cleanest implementation you could possibly get before your targeted release date.

**Disclaimer**: If you have core functions that you are OK with being part of the application forever, it is then OK for new functions to depend on these (core) old functions. SOLID Principles are recommendations, not gospel. It's like we striving for perfection. We will never get there no matter how hard we try. BUT, that should not stop up in trying our best to achieve it. In the end, the important thing is for us to be the best version of ourselves than we can be. Likewise, our code will NEVER be perfect. But, that should not stop us in developing the best applications we can. There are going to be situations when we would have to modify old code. We should be OK with that as long as it is not a common occurrence. The important thing is that, when opportunity present itself, we do a better job than the previous time to ensure these "violations" occur less often.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to save downloaded payload because it will be sitting in memory just to pass it to a save function, I had that to begin with then I switched to streams because i was hitting memory limits with large files. Now streams do provide chunks that i can be saving gradually with a separate saving function, However this brings us back to the actual question I'm asking, Which is how to access those chunks within the `donwloadFile.js` and at the time keep the function intact with a single purpose so to speak

Comment: @ZohirSalak "_I don't think it's a good idea to save downloaded payload because it will be sitting in memory just to pass it to a save function..._" - it will be in memory regardless you save it or not. Eventually, memory will be reclaimed by the garbage collector. So, I won't worry about that too much.

Comment: That is not what i meant, before i was downloading files as arraybuffer which broke because it couldn't hadnle files larger than `512MB`  streams don't work like that, they download files in chunks which do sit in memory but will never hit memory limits

Comment: @ZohirSalak if you are having problems with large files, perhaps you should try this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42614880/2851311

Comment: @ZohirSalak besides, these comments are deviating from the main point of my answer: The original method **does not** violate SRP. The only reason IMO to refactor will be to achieve cleaner code. However, I as stated in the disclaimer, all of these are recommendations, not gospel. In the end, you have to use your best judgment of when to apply these suggestions and when you should not.

Comment: I understand that, Im mainly asking this question because i want to starting learning how to clean my code, and that is why i tried to implement the solution you suggested, that is where i ended up back in the same issue that lead me to ask the question. The question about the original function was merely a side and small question and didn't want to post a second question just for that. The main question was at the bottom.